# Odd Size Tub Drain- 1 3/8" Coarse Thread

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, bathtub

I recently removed a drain from my fiberglass tub/shower enclosure. It didn't survive. The problem is that it the older 1 3/8 standard but coarse thread, not fine.

All I can find is fine in that size. Any ideas on a source or a solve? Could I somehow chase the threads of the new drain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A picture would be helpful. It's not quite clear which part didn't survive, and why you can't just replace the entire drain assembly.

Comment: Try these search results from google "1 3/8 course thread tub drain" https://www.google.com/search?q=1+3%2F8+coarse+thread+tub+drain&rlz=1C1GCEV_en&oq=1+3%2F8+course+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2.7259j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @brehma "1 3/8 **coarse** thread tub drain"...

Comment: @Daniel It took me all day to figure out what you're saying! DOH! I guess I have teaching on the mind. The quarter did just end. Lol

Comment: @brehma Yeah; eventually the neuron will fire, but sometimes it takes a while... been there, done that way too many times...